# Deduce center of circle from portion of circumference

Tags: geometry, best-fit-curve, best-fit

I have sequences of points forming arcs(?). I would like to deduce the best fit circular (or even ellipsoid) curve for these points.  Each arc has a relatively consistent change of angle across its length (that is partly how I isolate them).

An algorithm would be great (especially if explained so I can understand it), but since this is probably known territory, pointers to answers would also be good.  If all else fails some better search terms would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am not confident in using matrix transformations, and certainly not confident in coding solutions described in them.....  a solution without matrices would be much appreciated.

(I am fluent in c/java/kotlin languages so solutions in something like that would be easiest for me, but I am happy to work from any language or pseudocode).

Thanks in advance

---

Thanks to Renat for his solution - it works a treat. I am a little miffed that I do not understand the algorithm, but there is a reference and I can live with the ignorance for now.

For anyone needing the code translated to kotlin:

```
class Circle(val x: Int, val y: Int, val radius: Int) {
    companion object {
        /**
         * Find the best fit circle for a collection of points.
         * With many thanks to Renat:
         * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493481/deduce-center-of-circle-from-portion-of-circumference
         */
        fun fit(points: List<Point>): Circle {
            val sx = points.sumOf { it.x.toDouble() }
            val sy = points.sumOf { it.y.toDouble() }
            val sx2 = points.sumOf { it.x.toDouble() * it.x }
            val sy2 = points.sumOf { it.y.toDouble() * it.y }
            val sxy = points.sumOf { it.x.toDouble() * it.y }
            val sx3 = points.sumOf { it.x.toDouble() * it.x * it.x }
            val sy3 = points.sumOf { it.y.toDouble() * it.y * it.y }
            val sx2y = points.sumOf { it.x.toDouble() * it.x * it.y }
            val sxy2 = points.sumOf { it.x.toDouble() * it.y * it.y }

            val n = points.size;
            val s11 = n * sxy - sx * sy
            val s20 = n * sx2 - sx * sx
            val s02 = n * sy2 - sy * sy
            val s30 = n * sx3 - sx2 * sx
            val s03 = n * sy3 - sy * sy2
            val s21 = n * sx2y - sx2 * sy
            val s12 = n * sxy2 - sx * sy2
            val a = ((s30 + s12)*s02 - (s03 + s21)*s11) / (2*( s20 * s02 - s11 * s11));
            val b = ((s03 + s21)*s20 - (s30 + s12)*s11) / (2*( s20 * s02 - s11 * s11));
            val c = (sx2 + sy2 - 2*a*sx - 2*b*sy) / n;
            val radius = Math.sqrt(c + a*a + b*b);
            return Circle(a.roundToInt(), b.roundToInt(), radius.roundToInt())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it's a [Fitting a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting#Fitting_a_circle_by_geometric_fit) (or ellipse) problem. Which is solvable in linear time.

For code below I used [answer from this question from Math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898295/how-to-quickly-fit-a-circle-by-given-random-arc-points), which references [Régressions coniques, quadriques. Régressions linéaires et apparentées, circulaire, sphérique](https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique), pp 12-13, which uses a method of least squares to minimize the sum
[image]

(press 'Run code snipppet', and draw with mouse)

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

document.body.style.margin = 0;
canvas.style.position = 'fixed';

// get canvas 2D context and set him correct size
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
resize();

let points = [];
let unclicked = false;

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);

function getApproxCircle(p) {
  // Régressions coniques, quadriques, régressions linéaires et apparentées, circulaire, sphérique
  // pp 12-13
    let Sx = 0 
    let Sy = 0 
    let Sx2 = 0 
    let Sy2 = 0 
    let Sxy = 0 
    let Sx3 = 0 
    let Sy3 = 0 
    let Sx2y = 0
    let Sxy2 = 0
    for(point of p ){
        const [x,y] = [point.x,point.y]
        const [x2,y2] = [x*x,y*y]
        const [x3,y3] = [x2*x,y2*y]
        const xy    = x*y
        const [x2y,xy2] = [xy*x,xy*y]

        Sx += x
        Sy += y
        Sx2 += x2
        Sy2 += y2
        Sxy += xy
        Sx3 += x3
        Sy3 += y3
        Sx2y += x2y
        Sxy2 += xy2
    }

    const n = points.length;
    const s11 = n * Sxy - Sx * Sy
    const s20 = n * Sx2 - Sx * Sx
    const s02 = n * Sy2 - Sy * Sy
    const s30 = n * Sx3 - Sx2 * Sx
    const s03 = n * Sy3 - Sy * Sy2
    const s21 = n * Sx2y - Sx2 * Sy
    const s12 = n * Sxy2 - Sx * Sy2
    const a = ((s30 + s12)*s02 - (s03 + s21)*s11)
            / (2*( s20 * s02 - s11 * s11));
    const b = ((s03 + s21)*s20 - (s30 + s12)*s11)
            / (2*( s20 * s02 - s11 * s11));
    const c = (Sx2 + Sy2 - 2*a*Sx - 2*b*Sy) / n;
    const radius = Math.sqrt(c + a*a + b*b);
        
    return {
        center: {
            x: a,
          y: b
        },
        radius: radius
    };
}
function setPosition(e) {
  if (unclicked && e.buttons === 1) {
    unclicked = false;
        points = [];
  }
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
}

function resize() {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function draw(e) {
  if (e.buttons !== 1) { 
    unclicked = true;
    return;
  }
  
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
    clear();  

  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#c0392b';
  
  //point of drawn arc
  ctx.beginPath(); 
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  for(i=1; i<points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y); 
  }
  ctx.stroke(); 
  
  let approxCircle = getApproxCircle(points);
  
  //circle
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#3039cb77';
    ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(approxCircle.center.x, approxCircle.center.y, approxCircle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  // center of the circle
    ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(approxCircle.center.x, approxCircle.center.y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

And if it's needed to draw a circle by 3 points, there is a formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_2):

[image]
[image]

in Kotlin ([link to sandbox](https://pl.kotl.in/SexlGPMRf)):

```
data class Point(
        val x: Float,
        val y: Float
) {
    fun lenSquare() = x*x + y*y
}

fun main() {
    val A = Point(0f, 0f)
    val B = Point(0f, 2f)
    val C = Point(2f, 0f)
    
    val D = 2 * (A.x * (B.y - C.y)
                + B.x * (C.y - A.y)
                + C.x * (A.y - B.y))

    var lenASqr = A.lenSquare()
    var lenBSqr = B.lenSquare()
    var lenCSqr = C.lenSquare()
    val Ux = (lenASqr * (B.y - C.y)
                + lenBSqr * (C.y - A.y)
                + lenCSqr * (A.y - B.y)
             ) / D;
    val Uy = (lenASqr * (C.x - B.x)
                + lenBSqr * (A.x - C.x)
                + lenCSqr * (B.x - A.x)
             ) / D;
    val U = Point(Ux, Uy)

    println("A: $A")
    println("B: $B")
    println("C: $C")
    println("Circumcircle center: $U")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that ... I sort-of follow matrix algebra, but not with any confidence.  I am not sure that I could code the solution efficiently in my target language (kotlin).  I can read python - I just forgot to ask 'no matrices, please'.
The basic theory in algebra makes sense to me - but since the arcs that I have only approximate a line I will need to perform the calculations with multiple triples of points and average the results, so it needs to be efficient.

Comment: @DrPhill: I see no matrices in the posted code !? Averaging several solutions is not the best method. There are more global approaches, such as least-squares minimization.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Previous version with matrices wasn't a fit for the question actually.

Comment: Thanks Renat.  The fitting circle code is *exactly* what I wanted... without knowing what to ask for.  Wish I could upvote twice for the effort you put in.

Comment: No problem, I was an interesting experience for me as well, I learned this new term fitting-problem, and a bit of Kotlin, and a bit of working with Canvas in JS

Comment: Cool.  It makes me wonder if there is a best fit for ellipse algorithm out there.......

Comment: @DrPhill , found a python package `lsq-ellipse` with source code on Github, https://github.com/bdhammel/least-squares-ellipse-fitting/blob/881970f04313d6be254f670543a42cfd2475f2da/ellipse.py#L72 , it uses matrix operations from numpy library, if need be to translate it to another language it would require to find alternative library/implementation for those operations

Comment: Thanks @Renat I will look into that when I have the rest of the framework in place.  Detecting ellipses is currently out of scope but I am sure it will sneak its way back in.....