# Quality of circle fit for points (java/kotli/js/c)

Tags: geometry, best-fit-curve, best-fit

[A question I asked on recently SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493481/deduce-center-of-circle-from-portion-of-circumference) elicited an excellent solution for finding best fit circle for a collection of points in 2d space.
I now find that I need to quantify the quality of the circle fit, and not just determine the circle itself.  I do not understand the maths involved - could someone point me to a source of an algorithm to achieve this?
Any and all input gratefully received, but answers in a language that I can use (c/c++/java/kotlin/swift/js etc) would be especially helpful.  I am not familiary with matrix algebra so explanations/algorithms using matrices would be less helpful)

Thanks,

Phill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - mean squares:

```
    fun meanSquares(points: List<Point>): Int {
        val center = Point(x, y)
        val avSquareDiff =  points
            .map { (center.distance(it) - radius) }
            .map { it * it }
            .average()
        return sqrt(avSquareDiff).roundToInt()
    }
```

Average the squares of distance between each point and circle line,  take the square root for convenience in GUI.